# Convert an array of object to the array of string in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Using lodash I need to convert an array of object to the array of string.

Original array,

```
const tags = [{
    "display": "tag1",
    "value": "tag1"
}, {
    "display": "tag2",
    "value": "tag2"
}]
```

Expected result,

```
const tags = ["tag1", "tag2"]
```

I tried this way,

```
const data = [{
    "display": "tag1",
    "value": "tag1"
}, {
    "display": "tag2",
    "value": "tag2"
}]

    const result = _(data)
        .flatMap(_.values)
        .map((item) => { if (typeof item === 'string') { return item; } else { return; } })
        .value()
        console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: What did you tried ? Also, plain JS can do it, no need to use lodash for this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You dont need lodash, you can do with plain JS using map

**`DEMO`**

```js
const tags = [{
    "display": "tag1",
    "value": "tag1"
}, {
    "display": "tag2",
    "value": "tag2"
}]

var result = tags.map(a => a.display);
console.log(result);
```